# How to customize PS1 properly?

Tags: bash, prompt

I customized my bash with this in my bashrc

```
export PS1="\e[0;36m\h\e[m \e[0;33m\w/\e[m \e[0;31m\n\$ →\e[m  "
```

So I get something like this (with colors) :

```
Ahuri ~/Public/ 
$ →
```

But I am having problems with long commands. When I write a very long command that is longer than a line it starts overwriting my first line

Example :

```
Ahuri ~/Public/ 
$ → ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If I continue to add "^" I get:

```
Ahuri ~/Public/ 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

my "$ →" is overwritten, and then the whole line gets overwritten.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no issue with the `\n`. This is yet again the old escape sequence length problem: `\e[0m` and similar do not contribute to the actual length of the prompt, so you have to enclose them in `\[`..`\]` to indicate this to the interpreter:

```
PS1="\[\e[0;36m\]\h\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;33m\]\w/\[\e[m\]\n \[\e[0;31m\]\$ →\[\e[m\]  "
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler option is to use the `tput` sequences:

```
export PS1='\[$(tput setaf 4)\]\h\[$(tput sgr0)\] \[$(tput setaf 3)\]\w/\[$(tput sgr0)\]\n\[$(tput setaf 1)\]\$ →\[$(tput sgr0)\] '
```

The `\[` and `\]` enclose the terminal control sequences inserted by the command substitions (`$(tput … )`) so that the shell does not count them as printable output.
Using the command substitutions rather than hardwiring stuff further ensures that you get the *right* control sequences for whatever your terminal type is.

Comment: Are you sure? `tput` not seems to add anything special to solve the length calculation: http://pastebin.com/u28RTT5t

Comment: l0b0 has left unstated that xe has also added the missing `\[` and `\]`.  But this is the better answer (_with_ that omission stated) because the world largely doesn't use boldface to change colour any more.  _Boldface means boldface_.  Hardwiring control sequences in imitation of manatwork's answer often nowadays hardwires _the wrong control sequences for changing colour_; as people think of `0;` and `1;` as magic, rather than reset-all and boldface.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to display the additional line so you have no `\n` in `$PS1`.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how this is implemented?