# How to include commands in Bash's PS1 without breaking line length calculation?

Tags: bash, prompt

Tonin [pointed out a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592077/bash-prompt-and-echoing-colors-inside-a-function/13997892?noredirect=1#comment30942848_13997892) in my [default prompt](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/54ee46d965eb0ec4700439dd55cdf5bf387239b8/.bashrc#L60). Minimal example:

1. Set PS1:

   ```
   PS1='$(exit_code=$?; [[ $exit_code -eq 0 ]] || printf %s $(tput setaf 1) $exit_code $(tput sgr0) " ")$ '
   ```

   At this point, the prompt looks like this:

   ```
   $
   ```
2. Now trigger the exit code output by running:

   ```
   false
   ```

   Now the prompt contains the exit code in red at the beginning of the line:

   ```
   1 $
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>.
4. Type "false". Now the prompt contains only the search:

   ```
   (reverse-i-search)`false': false
   ```
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The resulting terminal history now contains the following:

```
1 $ch)`false': false
```

Expected output:

```
1 $ false
```

That is, it seems the history search output is *mixed* with the prompt and hiding the actual command which was run.

I tried working around this by [using `PROMPT_COMMAND`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997892/96588):

```
set_exit_code() {
    exit_code=$?
    [[ $exit_code -eq 0 ]] || printf %s $(tput setaf 1) $exit_code $(tput sgr0) " "
}
set_bash_prompt() {
    PS1='$(set_exit_code)$ ' # Double quotes give the same result
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=set_bash_prompt
```

This doesn't seem to work - the line looks exactly the same as before after searching and running.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This seems to be the continuation of http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71012

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111840/ps1-problem-messing-up-cli).  @qeirha mentioned that you have to tell bash that the sequence of characters should not be counted in the prompt's length, and you do that by enclosing it in `\[` `\]`.  Based on the example provided, here is one solution:

```
red=$(tput setaf 1)

reset=$(tput sgr0)

[ "$PS1" = "\\s-\\v\\\$ " ] && PS1='$(exit_code=$?; [[ $exit_code -eq 0 ]] || printf %s \[$red\] $exit_code \[$reset\] " ")$ '
```

Comment: No need to go to [ubuntu.se] for it. We already have enough answers to this question here too.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @manatwork!  I wanted to give proper credit for the explanation and supplied the reference as a courtesy.

Comment: Giving credit is not a problem. But while talking about problem: unescaped backslashes used to vanish from Markdown, so your plain \\[ became [ in your post, thus the displayed code was not functional by copy-pasting it into terminal. This can be avoided by using inline code or code block markup. ([How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting))

Comment: D'oh! I've already fixed the same issue for other `PS1` code, why didn't I see that one?

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @manatwork answer but keeping your code splitting the `PS1` compute in different functions, you can write your prompt the following way:

```
set_exit_code() {
    exit_code=$?
    [[ $exit_code -eq 0 ]] || printf "\[$(tput setaf 1)\] $exit_code \[$(tput sgr0)\] "
}
set_bash_prompt() {
    PS1="$(set_exit_code)$ " # with double quotes!
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=set_bash_prompt
```

Double quotes are mandatory both when setting `PS1` and when using `printf` in the function.

Comment: For future reference, use a bash function in your `.bashrc` - don't put code in a separate file and call that.

Answer (score 1):

```
PS1='$(exit_code=$?; [[ $exit_code -eq 0 ]] || printf %s \[$(tput setaf 1)\] $exit_code \[$(tput sgr0)\] " ")$ '
```

(Sorry, no explanation here. See [How to customize PS1 properly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71007/how-to-customize-ps1-properly) or any other question about prompt length calculation issues and `\[`..`\]`.)

Comment: To second @l0b0 question, I'll add that using PS1 and `\[...\]` works fine as long as you can put all the code you want to generate your prompt in a single string.  However, if you want to split your code into small functions, you come to a point where you cannot put the starting and ending brackets in the same string/function.  And that breaks line wrap.  Unless you resort to using `PROMPT_COMMAND` to recompute your `PS1` at each prompt.