# BASH - customizing PS1 to run a command

Tags: bash, colors, prompt

I wanted to modify my PS1 to run some commands every time. Let's say I want it so that if the last executed command was successful, it would add a green smile at the end of PS1, otherwise the smile should be red.
I extracted it to a function:

```
function exit_smile {

    EXITSTATUS="$?"
    RED="\[\e[1;31m\]"
    GREEN="\[\e[32;1m\]"

    if [ "${EXITSTATUS}" -eq 0 ]
    then
       SMILE="${GREEN}:)"
    else
       SMILE="${RED}:("
    fi

    echo -n "$SMILE"
}
```

and then tried both using `` `exit_smile` `` and `\$(exit_smile)` when modifying the PS1 variable, but it executes it once when modifying PS1 or prints literal `\[\e...\]` instead of a color.
For example

```
PROMPT="\u@\h \W"
PS1="${PROMPT} \$ \$(exit_smile) ${OFF}\n"
```

Gives `username@hostname ~ $ \[\e[32;1m\]:)` 
What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include commands in Bash's PS1 without breaking line length calculation?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105926/how-to-include-commands-in-bashs-ps1-without-breaking-line-length-calculation)

Comment: I believe that you need to put the string in single quotes, or add an extra layer of backslashes. To test, do `printf "%s\n" "$PS1"`; it should show all the dollar signs that you want to have evaluated when the prompt is issued.

Comment: @jasonwryan, The line length calculation breaks because of non-printing characters, and the solution is to add those `\[..\]`. They're already in place here, so this isn't much of a duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this has changed between versions<sup>(*)</sup>, but my man page for Bash says that

> Bash allows these prompt strings to be customized by inserting a  number of backslash-escaped special characters that are decoded as follows:
>
> *(list contains `\e`, `\[`, `\]` etc.)*
>
> **After** the string is decoded, it is expanded via parameter expansion, command substitution, ...

Which means that the `\[..\]` can't come from the command substitution, but must be there before that.

(It also means you could use `\u` or `\w` as arguments to a command substitution, and they'd get replaced before the command runs. And I have no idea what putting `\[..\]` inside a command substitution would do... This would make more sense the other way around.)

So, we'll have to put the color codes in separate expansions and protect them with `\[..\]` by hand. I'll use variables instead of command substitution, and also the `$'...'` expansion to get the ESC character:

```
prompt_smile() {
        if [ "$?" = 0 ] ; then
                smile=' :) '
                smilecolor=$'\e[1;32m'
        else
                smile=' :( '
                smilecolor=$'\e[1;31m'
        fi
        normalcolor=$'\e[0m'
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_smile
PS1='\u@\h \W \$ \[$smilecolor\]$smile\[$normalcolor\]\n'
```

<sub>(* the reason I wonder about that, is that the answers to the older and [similar but no so duplicate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105926/how-to-include-commands-in-bashs-ps1-without-breaking-line-length-calculation) seem to output the `\[..\]` from within an expansion)</sub>

Comment: Thank you. It's not an ideal solution, as it leaves variables `smile` and `smilecolor` public, but at least it works.

Comment: @Szymon, they're only visible within your shell (unless you export them). Rename them something like `__p_smile` etc, and it'll be quite hard to hit them accidentally.